# How to run onClick before onBlur takes place?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this tricky problem:

I have a text input field and a **ul tag** with a list of suggestions which when pressed should populate that input field.

```
export default function SimpleDemo() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const updateText = (new_text) => {
        setText(new_text)
        setShow(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={text}
                onChange={(e) => { setText(e.target.value) }}
                onClick={() => { setShow(true) }}
                onBlur={() => { setShow(false) }} // because of this my updateText() handler never runs
            />
            {show && (
                <ul>
                    <li onClick={() => { updateText("Some Text") }}>Some Text</li>
                    <li onClick={() => { updateText("Suggestion 2") }}>Suggestion 2</li>
                    <li onClick={() => { updateText("Hello World") }}>Hello World</li>
                </ul>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

It works as expected until I add `onBlur` handler to my input field. (because I don't need to show suggestions when I'm not in that field)

When I add onBlur to my text input, my **li tag** onClick handler `updateText();` never runs, thus never populating my input. They don't run because my **ul tag** gets deleted first thus there are no **li tag** elements with onClick handlers that could be clicked.

The only hack I found so far is wrapping contents of my onBlur in a setTimeout() with an arbitrary timeout duration. But it proved to be unreliable with a small timeout, and a high timeout makes it seem laggy on the front end.

Whats a reliable solution?

I'm trying to clone HTML **datalist tag** functuanality (because it lets me style it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `onClick` handlers with `onMouseDown`. They fire before the blur event.